# Как добавить просто число на диаграмму (ms excel)?

Tags: excel

Допустим есть график по определенным данным с таблицы. 
Но есть ряд чисел, самое большое из которых, нужно отобразить на графике.
В виде точки с подписью данных, либо в виде сноски под графиком.
Если это невозможно, то пусть будет полноценная линия, но последняя точка этой линии всегда с выноской данных.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Добавить на график ряд с этим числом (размножено на диапазон). отобразится в виде горизонтальной линии. Не то? Покажите график и пример желаемого.

Comment: Нет, не то. В том то и проблема, я не знаю возможно ли это реализовать вообще.
По сути нужна просто точка с выноской в числовом виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График строится обычно. Данные для построения:

```
=Лист1!$B$2:$G$4
```

Ряд для отображение максимального числа содержит формулы, показывающие ошибку:

```
=НД()
```

В нужном месте вместо ошибки выводим максимальное значение отдельного диапазона:

```
=МАКС(C8:G8)
```

При построении график игнорирует ошибки и строит линию по имеющимся числовым значениям. Т.к. значение одно, то и линий нет. Чтобы отображалась точка, нужно установить маркер (*Формат_ряда_данных-Параметры_маркера*)